# how to extract this information as one node in xpath1.0?

Tags: python, html, xpath, web-scraping, scrapy

```
<a href="../legislation/Legislation.aspx?id=62397"><span style="cursor:pointer;" title="weight = 2">Expiry Date</span> + 5 years</a>
```

how to extract the data as `Expiry data+ 5 years` in one line code?

```
response.xpath('//tr[@style="cursor:pointer;"]/td[1]/a/span/text() | //tr[@style="cursor:pointer;"]/td[1]/a/text()').extract()
```

returns two elements `Expiry code` and `+5 days`

And I works on a table that means there are many herfs like this, and for each one I want to concat the information

[u'Expiry Date', u' + 5 years', u'Due Date', u' + 4 years', u'Creation', u' + 3 years'] but I want [Expiry Date+ 5 years, Due Date+4 years, Creation+3 years]
thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

You can join all of the text nodes from inside the `a`:

```
"".join(response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'Legislation')]//text()").extract())
```

Demo:

```
$ scrapy shell index.html
In [1]: "".join(response.xpath("//a[contains(@href, 'Legislation')]//text()").extract())
Out[1]: u'Expiry Date + 5 years'
```

Comment: hi, thanks for your help.  but I updated the problem, for its a list we get from the xpath

Comment: @printemp sure, join the list, as shown in the answer.

Comment: [u'Expiry Date', u' + 5 years', u'Due Date', u' + 4 years', u'Creation', u' + 3 years']     but I want  [Expiry Date+ 5 years, Due Date+4 years, Creation+3 years]

Comment: @printemp sorry, but I was answering the question you've asked. I don't see these `Due Date` or `Creation` in the question.

Answer (score 0):

finally, get a solution, even though not elegant....

```
    retentionEvent=[]
    retentionPeriod = leghxs.xpath('//a[contains(@href, "Legislation")]')
    for each in retentionPeriod:
           event=each.xpath( "span/text()").extract()

           period = each.xpath("text()").extract()
           retentionEvent.append( event+period)`
```

then here you get a list of list, you want  to assign each list(ex: expiry date+5 years) to the item[key] when using scrapy to crawl data

```
for eachretention in retentionEvent:
     item = RetentionElement()
     item['time']=eachretention
```